# How to display a Java object in JSP page?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat

I have Java object with some fields

```
private static Film film;
    static  {
        film = new Film();
        film.setTitle("Inception");
        film.setYear(2010);
        film.setGenre("sci-fi");
        film.setWatched(true);
```

I want to display all fields on my jsp page and I using this construction

```
<body>
${film.toString()}
</body>
```

But it's not working and I get just empty page.
How can I fix this? Or maybe use other way?

Controler

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView allFilms() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("films");
        modelAndView.addObject("film", film);
        return modelAndView;
```

Comment: Have you bound the variable to an attribute?

Comment: While the code you provided is correct, you need to provide more details. What do you mean by _empty page_? Does it just have an empty body or is it entirely empty? What HTTP code does the GET request return (check with `curl`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that I didn't add thymeleaf link to header `xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"`